# Can't login to FTP site using PHP but can with Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, ftp

I'm trying to access a URL like:
`ftp.somesite.com/content/somefile.txt`

Using login *myname* and pass *mypass*.

I can enter these in IE9 when they are requested and it opens the file right up.  However, when I try this in PHP or Firefox I'm given a 550 error regarding the file `/myname/content/somefile.txt`.

What is wrong and why are both PHP and Firefox changing the file location to include `myname` as part of the file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out how to resolve this in both PHP and Firefox.

To prevent the addition of the username to the directory structure, add another "/" to the start of the file path.  This forces the root dir.

In other words:

> ftp.somesite.com//content/somefile.txt

Answer (score 0):

> ftp://username:password@ftp.somesite.com/content/somefile.txt

This is a valid URL.  Sometimes FTP clients will put your username@hostname in the URL when you login.  This isn't a problem, it is just for clarity, and also allows you to copy and paste that URL with the username.

Comment: If I go to "ftp://username:password@ftp.somesite.com/content/somefile.txt" in either PHP or FireFox, either still gives me the error "550 /username/content/somefile.txt: Cannot find the file specified".  The problem is, "/username/content/somefile.txt" doesn't exist but "/content/somefile.txt" does.

Answer (score 0):

When you log into FTP, your base directory may not be the same as your htdoc/web server directory.

What is the full file path for the file you wish to download?

Ex:

```
/root/somefile.txt
/home/user/test/somefile.txt
/var/www/site/content/somefile.txt
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the full file path is "/content/somefile.txt".  This is just what I have been given, and starting from the root dir I can see the "content" dir there.  There is no user dir "myname".

Comment: Are you adding the FTP extension, an fsock request, stream or cURL request to get the file?